# Python django - remember me

Tags: django, authentication

I am a newbie in django . I need to implement "remember me" thing . I am not using built in login thing for this thing . 
I have written this function

```
def abc(request):
     if request.method=="POST":
         m = Deletelater.objects.get(Username=request.POST['Username'])
         if m.Password==request.POST['Password']:
             request.session['member_id'] = m.id
             if not request.POST.get('remember_me', None):
                 request.session.set_expiry(0)
             return render(request,'hat/abc.html')
```

What I need to do after this ? If you look here http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1881/ 
you will find something like this

```
 return auth_views.login(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

What should I write in my function instead of this line(this is for inbuilt login ,i think)?
Or any new Idea how to implement "remember me" without using inbuilt login?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of login(...), you should write something which has the same behavior than the django built-in login view. Take a look at [the github project to have an idea](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py)

The most important is to set the session of course.

Comment: complicated stuff ! If I want to check other things too ,like checking  if password is correct or not , or if user's name is present in database or not(as you can see in the function that I have written)...Can I use it with built in django login function(and obviously the remember password thing)....Plz guide me through this

Comment: Why don't you make your stuff in your views (like check pwd and remember me) and call auth.views.login after, as in your djangosnippet example?